# How to find syntax error in my Javascript code for React Native easily?

Tags: react-native

I am just starting to try out React Native. One of the annoying issues I found is that there is no way to find syntax errors in my JS code easily. When I have a syntax error (say a missing comma), there is no place within XCode, React Packager, or Chrome debugger session that shows what/where the error is. Instead, I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in XCode that does not help me at all.

Given that syntax errors in our code happen all the time during development process, there must be an easy way to deal with this in React Native development, right? Could someone show me the way?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is an easy way.

Although I do leverage the JSX Harmony parser that is currently in Jetbrains IDE’s. The whole idea of having an **Integrated** DE is that it should help with this. Here is an example where issue are highlighted on the right side:

> unneeded comma
>   [image]
>
> comma expected
>   [image]

Comment: Thanks bro. Since I use Sublime Text, I found this article at https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/lint-like-it-s-2015-6987d44c5b48 and followed it to install ESLint to Sublime Text 3. I think that is an acceptable solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) plugins for most editors, which when setup with a good .jshintrc works very well with React Native.